# Saxon XSLT processing on pre-parsed XML tree

Tags: xpath, xslt, saxon

I'm using Saxon 12 with Java 17 to transform an input XML document using XSLT, and it's working fine. The relevant code looks like this:

```java
final Processor saxonProcessor = new Processor(false);
final XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = saxonProcessor.newXsltCompiler();
…
final XsltExecutable xsltStylesheet;
try (final InputStream xsltInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(…)) {
  xsltStylesheet = xsltCompiler.compile(new StreamSource(xsltInputStream));
}
final Xslt30Transformer xsltTransformer = xsltStylesheet.load30();
final String text;
try (final InputStream xmlInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(…));
    final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()) {
  xsltTransformer.applyTemplates(new StreamSource(xmlInputStream), saxonProcessor.newSerializer(stringWriter));
  text = stringWriter.toString();
}
//text now has XSLT output
```

The important part is `xsltTransformer.applyTemplates(new StreamSource(xmlInputStream), …)`, which assumes that XSLT will read in an XML source file, parse that XML document, and then apply the XSLT stylesheet to it.

But it turns out that for each of my (tens of thousands of) XML documents, I want to perform various operations:

1. I want to extract various pieces of data using potentially multiple XPath expressions to extract different pieces of information.
2. I may want to transform the document multiple times using XSLT in order to produce different forms of it.

The Saxon XPath API seems to work on a parsed XML document, specifically a `XdmItem` which I set using `xpathSelector.setContextItem(document)`. (I haven't tried it but that's my best guess so far.) I would infer then that I could perform the first part (performing multiple XPath queries) on the same document without reparsing the document.

But then does Saxon XSLT require me to reparse the source document again each time? Is there a way to tell Saxon XSLT to apply the stylesheet to the `XdmItem` I've already parsed, without parsing it again and again each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a tree representation of a source document by doing

```
DocumentBuilder builder = saxonProcessor.newDocumentBuilder();
XdmNode doc = builder.build(...);
```

You can call the `Transformer.applyTemplates()` method to process an `XdmNode` by noting that `XdmNode` implements `XdmValue` and there is a version of `applyTemplates` that expects an `XdmValue`.

Similarly, an `XdmNode` is an `XdmItem` and can therefore be passed directly to the XPath processor.

Comment: Ah, indeed. Thanks! I'm not sure how I missed that—probably because my mind is used to looking for DOM-related interfaces instead of XDM-related classes after all these years. That seems to work just fine.